# Solve the integral equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

$$y(x) = 2 + \int_8^x (t-ty(t))dt$$
I am having a very hard time doing this problem.
(i) Solve the separable differential equation $$y'(x) = x − xy(x)$$ to get $$y(x) = 1 + c \cdot e^{−x^2/2}$$
(ii) Using your answer to part (i), solve the integral equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y(x) = 2 + \int_8^x (t-t y(t)) dt \,\, (\clubsuit)$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$, we get that
$$y'(x) = x - x y(x) \implies y'(x) + x \cdot y(x) =x \implies y'(x) \cdot e^{x^2/2} + x \cdot e^{x^2/2} \cdot y(x) = x \cdot e^{x^2/2}$$
Hence, we get that
$$\dfrac{d \left(y(x) \cdot e^{x^2/2}\right)}{dx} = \dfrac{d (e^{x^2/2})}{dx}$$
Hence,
$$y(x)  = 1 + c \cdot e^{-x^2/2} \,\, (\spadesuit)$$
To find $c$, plug in $(\spadesuit)$ into $(\clubsuit)$.

Comment: so would c=2? or 8 since y(8)=2? or should i just completely disregard the 8 because of the FTC?